# Rename-Item is not replacing the file name (name ends in a period?)

Tags: powershell, replace

in following PowerShell code:

```
dir "D:\Test\New folder" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.','PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.'}
```

what I am trying to do is replace all files within D:\Test\New folder that have PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd. in their filename with PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd. So basically just to remove the comma before Ltd.

When executing the script in PowerShell nothing gets renamed. Any idea why? I believe it is something to do with & and Brackets () as when I'm doing the same for filenames without those chars it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: `-replace [regex]::Escape ('PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.'), 'PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.'` Also append switch `-File` to your Get-ChildItem (dir) cmdlet, otherwise you're trying to rename subfolders as well

Comment: Or just `-NewName {$_.Name.Replace('PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.','PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.')}`, regex is unnecessary here

Comment: Hi Both, thank you for your reply unfortunatelly non of this worked. Files are still not renamed.

Comment: A file with no extension has no period at the end in some contexts?

Comment: Hi all, apologize as I'm using confidential data I was misspelling what I need to replace in my script so both of your recommendations actually worked now that I tried it again:

@Theo
`dir "D:\Test\New folder" | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace [regex]::Escape('PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.'),'PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.''}`


@MathiasR.Jessen
`dir "D:\Test\New folder" | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace('PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.','PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.')}`

Thank you everyone for quick replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or backslash the parens for the regex.  I wonder if -replace should give a warning.  The parens are used for grouping.

```
'PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.' -replace 'PP&C Test \(Bank\), Ltd.',
                                  'PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.'

PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.
```

What escape() returns.  I don't see why the spaces are escaped.  `.` means any character.

```
[regex]::escape('PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.')

PP&C\ Test\ \(Bank\),\ Ltd\.
```

It seems to require taking off the period at the end.  It's quite odd.  I guess there is no period.

```
dir | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_PP&C Test \(Bank\), Ltd.',
  '_PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
C:\users\admin\foo\_PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd Destination:
C:\users\admin\foo\_PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd".


dir | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_PP&C Test \(Bank\), Ltd',
  '_PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
C:\users\admin\foo\_PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd Destination:
C:\users\admin\foo\_PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd".
```

To get-childitem there's a period, but not to the name property:

```
dir '_PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.'

    Directory: C:\Users\admin\foo

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           1/31/2022 12:52 PM              4 _PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd.


dir | % name

_PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd
```

Comment: Thank for repy, unfortunatelly no luck, still doesnt rename them. dir "D:\Test\New folder" | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '_PP&C Test \(Bank\), Ltd.','_PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.'}

Comment: With the backslashes?  You can test with -whatif.  Why is there an underline now?

Comment: yeah it didin't work. File name has underline as well basically that is not the full name of the file, it has more before underline. But the part I want to change is after underline.

Comment: I apologize I was misspelling in my PowerShell code as I have confidential data so _PP&C Test (Bank), Ltd was just an example. But Backslashes actually worked. So Final code I used is: `dir "D:\Test\New folder" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'PP&C Test \(Bank\), Ltd.','PP&C Test (Bank) Ltd.'}` Thank you very much!